# If we can see only visual light then why we can't see other electromagnetic radiation as they also a type of light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

Why we can't see other than visual light??

Comment: I guess this question is so short, showing no research effort into the human eye spectral sensitivity, that it can be considered defficient at physics.stackexchange.com. However, it is very pertinent for evolutionary biology - WHY can't we see other than visual light, when other species do? Ant this has been discussed e.g. here https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58005/are-there-animal-species-that-sense-infrared-light-with-their-eyes/58051

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we see infrared light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209854/why-cant-we-see-infrared-light) Even though this one is for IR light, the answers explain why UV light can't be seen.

Comment: We can't see other than visual light _by definition_.